# Splitting field of an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $P(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$; I am interested its splitting field. I know that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle P(x)\rangle $ have one of the roots of $P(x)$, and that regardless of what root $\xi$ we take the field $\mathbb{Q}(\xi)$ obtained by adjoining $\xi$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle P(x)\rangle$

I think think that if two field are isomorphic then a polynomial is irreducible over one of them implies it's irreducible over the second (is this true ? is it an iff claim ?)

From here I think that adding one root implies we added them all and so we know the splitting field of $P(x)$.

Are some of my claims wrong ? (why ?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to be careful about what you mean when you say "if two fields are isomorphic then a polynomial is irreducible over one of them if and only if it is irreducible over the second", since that statement may not even make sense as written.

Rather: suppose that $F$ and $K$ are two fields, and $\sigma\colon F\to K$ is a field isomorphism between them. Then $\sigma$ extends to an isomorphism of rings, $\sigma\colon F[x]\to K[x]$, by acting on the coefficients. Let $g(x)\in F[x]$ be a polynomial, and let $\sigma g(x)$ be the corresponding polynomial in $K[x]$. Then $g(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ if and only if $\sigma g(x)$ is irreducible in $K[x]$. This is true because $\sigma$ is an *isomorphism* between $F[x]$ and $K[x]$, so any factorization in one of the two is transfered, via $\sigma$ or $\sigma^{-1}$, into a factorization on the other.

No, it does not follow that adding one root adds all of them.

For example, take $x^3-2$. There are two complex roots and one real root, $\sqrt[3]{2}$, $\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$, and $\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2}$, where $\omega=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$.

We know that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^3-2\rangle$, and likewise
$$\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})\cong\mathbb{Q}(\omega^2\sqrt[3]{2})\cong\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\cong\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{\langle x^3-2\rangle}.$$
But $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ cannot contain all roots of $x^3-2$: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}$, and the "other" two roots are not.

The result just tells you that there is an *isomorphism over $\mathbb{Q}$* between $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\omega\sqrt[3]{2})$ that maps $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$; but once you do that, you "lose" $\sqrt[3]{2}$. That is a root in the domain *which is not in the codomain*. So you don't necessarily get all roots by adding a single one.

Comment: Really clears things up, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No it does not mean that adding one root gives you all the roots. For example let us calculate the splitting field of $x^4 - 6 \in \Bbb{Q}[x]$. By Eisenstein's Criterion with $p= 2$ this polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$. Now we find the roots of this polynomial in $\Bbb{C}$ to be

$$\sqrt[4]{6}e^{2 k \pi i/3} \hspace{2mm} \text{for} \hspace{2mm} k=0, \ldots 5.$$

Now you may guess that adjoining one root, say $\sqrt[4]{6}e^{2 \pi i/3}$ is enough to give us the splitting field. But then we have a problem because

$$\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{6}e^{2 \pi i/3}) \cong \Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^4 - 6) \cong \Bbb{Q}[\sqrt[4]{6}].$$

The field on the right hand side only contains *two* of the roots of the polynomial $x^4 -6$, so there must be something wrong. In fact the splitting field is actually

$$\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{6},e^{2\pi i/3}) \cong \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{6}, \sqrt{3}i)$$

that has degree 8 over $\Bbb{Q}$. It is a good exercise which you should do to show why this is the splitting field.

In some polynomial rings over certain fields, adjoining one root to the field *does* give you all the roots. Consider the polynomial

$$f(x) = x^p - x - a$$

in $\big(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\big)[x]$ with $a \neq 0$. Then in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$, no matter what value we substitute in for $x$ by Fermat's Little Theorem $f(b) = a$ for all $b \in \big(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\big)$. Now create a root for this polynomial in the field extension

$$\big(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}[x]\big)/(x^p - x - a).$$

Call that root $\gamma$. Now we know that this field must contain $\big(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\big)$ because

$$\big(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\big) \subset \big(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}[\gamma]\big) \cong  \big(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}[x]\big)/(x^p - x - a).$$

Now we can view the polynomial $x^p - x - a$ as sitting inside $$\big(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}[\gamma]\big)[x].$$ Furthermore, this is a polynomial ring over a field because the element $\gamma$ is algebraic over $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$. We know any polynomial in a polynomial ring over a field can have at most $\deg f$ roots. In your case if we find $\deg f$ distinct roots for the polynomial $f(x) = x^p - x - a$ *lying in that field*, we must have found all of them. The roots of $f(x)$ are distinct because the greatest common divisor of $f(x)$ and its formal derivative $f'(X) = px^{p-1} - 1 = -1$ is 1.

Now notice for any $k \in \Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$,

$$\begin{eqnarray*} f(\gamma + k) &=& (\gamma + k)^p - \gamma - k -a\\
&=& \gamma^k + k^p - \gamma - k - a \hspace{2mm} \text{(Using the fact that $p| \binom{p}{i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq p-1$})\\
&=& \gamma^k - \gamma - a \hspace{6mm} \text{(Fermat's Little Theorem shows that $k^p - k = 0$)}\\
&=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}$$

because $\gamma$ is a root of $f$. Letting $k$ vary from $0$ to $p-1$ shows that we have $p$ distinct roots for $f(x)$ lying in the field extension $\big(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\big)[\gamma]$. So we have just seen an example where adjoining one root of a polynomial gives us all of the roots.

I hope this helps!